# How to sum keys and multiply keys and values from dictionary in column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function, dictionary

In my dataframe a have column with dictionaries where keys and values are numeric:

```
col1        type
1       {4: 1, 8: 2, 4: 3}    
2       {10: 2, 8: 1, 3: 3}    
2       {5: 2, 2: 3}
```

I want to create two new columns: first one is equal to the sum of keys, second is equal to the sum of keys value pairs multiplications. So desired results must be:

```
col1        type               col2      col3
1       {4: 1, 8: 2, 4: 3}      16        32   
2       {10: 2, 8: 1, 3: 3}     21        37
2       {5: 2, 2: 3}            7         16
```

How to do that? When I do `df["col2"] = sum(df.type.keys())` it puts same value in each row in column col2

When I do `sum(df.type[0])` it rightly calculates 16.

Comment: Did you see what `df.type.keys()` gives? Is it what you thought you'd get?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi no it gives incorrect answer. but which function will extract keys thought?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi well when I do sum(df.type[0]) it rightly calculates 16.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- `{4: 1, 8: 2, 4: 3}` is actually `{4: 3, 8: 2}`, because the key `4` is used twice, and the second usage overrides the first. Try `print({4: 1, 8: 2, 4: 3})`.
- `df.type.keys()` gives you the keys of the Series `df.type`, which is the index (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.keys.html)). `print(df.type.keys())` should output something like `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)`.

To achieve your goal you could use [`.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and do the following:

```
df["col2"] = df.type.map(sum)
df["col3"] = df.type.map(lambda d: sum(k * v for k, v in d.items()))
```

Result:

```
   col1                 type  col2  col3
0     1         {4: 3, 8: 2}    12    28
1     2  {10: 2, 8: 1, 3: 3}    21    37
2     2         {5: 2, 2: 3}     7    16
```