# Add column to Pandas dataframe based on dictionary lookup multiplication then sum

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : [1 ,2, 3],
    'pts': [25,20,9],
    'ast': [8, 14, 7],
    'reb': [1, 4, 9],
    'oth': [5,6,7],
    'tov': [4, 2, 1]
})
print(df)

   id  pts  ast  reb  oth  tov
0   1   25    8    1    5    4
1   2   20   14    4    6    2
2   3    9    7    9    7    1
```

I want to essentially apply some weights/multiply certain columns then sum them up and make that a new column (`score`). Not every column in the `df` has a lookup mapping.

I can do this by manually applying the math to each column via a function:

```
def f(in_df):
  return in_df['pts'] + (in_df['reb'] * 1.2) + (in_df['ast'] * 1.5) - df['tov']

df['score'] = f(df)
print(df)

   id  pts  ast  reb  oth  tov  score
0   1   25    8    1    5    4   34.2
1   2   20   14    4    6    2   43.8
2   3    9    7    9    7    1   29.3
```

I want to accomplish it using a dictionary lookup though:

```
score_dict = {'pts': 1, 'reb': 1.2, 'ast': 1.5, 'tov': -1}

# Something like ..?
df['score'] = df[?].map(lambda d: sum(k * v for k, v in score_dict.items()))
```

I was looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69981936/how-to-sum-keys-and-multiply-keys-and-values-from-dictionary-in-column) and trying to implement a mapping like below. That solution takes a single column though for the mapping; I don't know how to implement it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly, you want to do a dot-product of the "weights" per column, i.e.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : [1 ,2, 3],
    'pts': [25,20,9],
    'ast': [8, 14, 7],
    'reb': [1, 4, 9],
    'tov': [4, 2, 1]
}).set_index('id')

df2 = pd.Series({'pts': 1, 'reb': 1.2, 'ast': 1.5, 'tov': -1})
df['score'] = df.dot(df2)

df
```

[out]:

```
    pts ast reb tov score
id                  
1   25  8   1   4   34.2
2   20  14  4   2   43.8
3   9   7   9   1   29.3
```

Comment: I updated the question. There can be columns in the `df` not included in the series.

Comment: Then do a subset of the columns you have on df2, e.g. `df['score'] = df[['pts', 'ast']].dot(df2[['pts', 'ast']])`

Comment: That's the best approach IMO. You can use `df['score'] = df[list(score_dict)].dot(pd.Series(score_dict))`

Comment: I added a [comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78005853/16343464) of the different answers

Comment: Nice job on the perf plots!

Answer (score 2):

multiplies each column of the DataFrame `df[['pts', 'reb', 'ast', 'tov']]` by its corresponding weight specified in `score_dict` and then sums along the columns axis to get the score column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'pts': [25, 20, 9],
    'ast': [8, 14, 7],
    'reb': [1, 4, 9],
    'tov': [4, 2, 1]
})


score_dict = {'pts': 1, 'reb': 1.2, 'ast': 1.5, 'tov': -1}

# Multiply each column by its weight and sum along columns axis
df['score'] = (df[['pts', 'reb', 'ast', 'tov']] * pd.Series(score_dict)).sum(axis=1)
print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   id  pts  ast  reb  tov  score
0   1   25    8    1    4   34.2
1   2   20   14    4    2   43.8
2   3    9    7    9    1   29.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["score"] = (df[score_dict.keys()] * score_dict.values()).sum(axis=1)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id  pts  ast  reb  oth  tov  score
0   1   25    8    1    5    4   34.2
1   2   20   14    4    6    2   43.8
2   3    9    7    9    7    1   29.3
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is with the `mul` method

```py
df.assign(score=df.mul(pd.Series(score_dict),axis=1).sum(axis=1))

   id  pts  ast  reb  oth  tov  score
0   1   25    8    1    5    4   34.2
1   2   20   14    4    6    2   43.8
2   3    9    7    9    7    1   29.3
```

Under the hood, pandas takes care of alignment between the pandas objects, converting non column matches to null, before summing to get the final output.

another option would be to populate the dictionary with all column labels in `df` before multiplying:

```py
score_dict = {key:score_dict.get(key, 0) for key in df}
df.assign(score=df.mul(score_dict,axis=1).sum(axis=1))
   id  pts  ast  reb  oth  tov  score
0   1   25    8    1    5    4   34.2
1   2   20   14    4    6    2   43.8
2   3    9    7    9    7    1   29.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there were many suggestions, here is a comparison of the timings for different lengths of `df`.

All approaches are relatively similar* except for the [`dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) product that is significantly (10-20x) faster.

[image: timing comparison]

** sammywemmy's approaches are a bit slower, but they return a copy of the DataFrame which is inherently more costly than assigning a single column.*

Perfplot code:

```
import pandas as pd
import perfplot

score_dict = {'pts': 1, 'reb': 1.2, 'ast': 1.5, 'tov': -1}

def setup(N):
    cols = list(score_dict)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((N, len(cols))),
                        columns=cols)
    
def TheHungryCub(df):
    df['score'] = (df[['pts', 'reb', 'ast', 'tov']] * pd.Series(score_dict)).sum(axis=1)
    return df

def alvas(df):
    df['score'] = df[list(score_dict)].dot(pd.Series(score_dict))
    return df

def Andrej(df):
    df['score'] = (df[score_dict.keys()] * score_dict.values()).sum(axis=1)
    return df

def sammywemmy1(df):
    return df.assign(score=df.mul(pd.Series(score_dict),axis=1).sum(axis=1))

def sammywemmy2(df):
    score_dict2 = {key:score_dict.get(key, 0) for key in df}
    return df.assign(score=df.mul(score_dict2, axis=1).sum(axis=1))

b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=setup,
    kernels=[TheHungryCub, alvas, Andrej, sammywemmy1, sammywemmy2],
    n_range=np.logspace(1, 8, num=10),
    xlabel='len(df)',
    equality_check=None,
    max_time=10
)

b.show()
```